# Can I increase the amount of Dedicated Memory for my NVIDIA graphics card?

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card

I have an old laptop that has an NVIDIA GeForce 9600M GT,
it's got 2046mb of Total Available Graphics Memory, and 512mb of Dedicated Video Memory(VRAM).
It's running on Windows 10 64-bit.
I was wondering if it was possible to increase the amount of VRAM for that graphics card.

[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8z6od.png)

Comment: It might be possible to replace the entire graphics card. The 9600M GT was available in an MXM form, and there are newer MXM graphics cards available.

Comment: I guess i could look into that

Comment: @MSalters is it also possible to change the CPU?

Comment: @hfehsfiqfheishfoQ Depends on laptop model. Google it first, if answers don't turn out helpful, ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.**

Dedicated memory is the amount of memory in dedicated memory chips soldered somewhere on GPU's circuit board. There's exactly 512 MB of memory soldered there, no more, no less.